# How to change the format of createddate and lastmodified date in flow salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow, datetime

How should I change the format of date from 2022-10-18T12:53:52.000+0000 to 10/18/2022, 6:23 PM in flow salesforce.

Comment: Hi @user123701 - eleborate bit more by adding: where are doing it. i.e. screen flow or record triggered flow. What is the exact step, etc.

Comment: I am doing it in Record triggered flow and Trying to compare createddate and lastmodifieddate. when both are equal I'll update the record. Since createddate and lastmodifieddate are standard field so it takes this format (2022-10-18T12:53:52.000+0000) but while comparing I do not want to consider milliseconds and hence want to convert it to this format(10/18/2022, 6:23 PM). But I'm not able to figure out what needs to be done for conversion.

Comment: Can you please paste your code by editing your question? Also, please take a moment to read this article, on [how to ask a good question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) which would help you updating your question with necessary details.

Comment: @Mahmood, thanks for you feedback. I'm not writing a code here. I'm updating the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly in flow. But there is a workaround for this. You can create two formula fields of return-type text. You can convert the DateTime field based on your requirement and then use those fields to compare in flow.
Here is example for formula field -
`TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))) + '/' +  TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))) + '/' +  TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))) + ', ' +  TEXT(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate))) + ':' +  TEXT(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)))`

Upvote if this helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the scenario in my org with Record-trigger flow. Given below is the debug log

[image]

As you can see in the image above using the [formula](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_design_formulas.htm&type=5), **the date format is exactly what you are looking for** (17/10/2022, 17:14, i.e. without milliseconds). And the formula is very simple (see image2 below)

Label: `LastModifiedDateActualValue`

Formula value: `{!$Record.LastModifiedDate}`

[image]

Using the above POC, you can create 2 formulas, one for `CreatedDate` and one for `LastModifiedDate` and then use the in the flow logic.

Comment: I tried this one, but even now its considering this format (2022-10-18T12:53:52.000+0000) as the Data type is Date/Time.

Comment: Did you create 2 formulas one for createddate and one for LastModifiedDate? and then use those formulas in your logic?

Comment: yes, I did the same...even though its not taking this format(10/18/2022, 6:23 PM)

Comment: So, if you created your formula with **DataType** as `TEXT` then you will see millisecond value but if you create your formula with **DataType** as `Date/Time` (see image 2) then it omits the millisecond part.

Comment: I've not created with Text Datatype. I've only created with Date/Time Datatype and it consider millisecods also for updating the record.

Comment: Can you please share your flow screen with formulas here

Comment: CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate are already have Date/Time format. So why are we again doing the same thing?